# I have a long data set. How do I convert to wide format while using a rank function to limit the number of columns created?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, dcast

I have a data set in a long format. Some records only have one manufacturer, some records are duplicated because there are multiple manufacturers associated with each record.

For example, I have the following data:

```
id      manufacturer
111     AAA
222     AAA
222     BBB
222     CCC
222     DDD
333     CCC
333     DDD
444     EEE
```

Using dplyr, I added a rank so I am able to count the number of manufacturers.

```
df %>% 
  select(id, manufacturer) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(manufacturer, ties.method = "first"))
```

To get:

```
id      manufacturer    rank
111     AAA             1
222     AAA             1
222     BBB             2
222     CCC             3
222     DDD             4
333     CCC             1
333     DDD             2
444     EEE             1
```

I've tried dcast which gets me close, but I'm not quite there.

```
dcast(df, id ~ rank)
```

When I use dcast I get:

```
id     1    2    3    4
111    1    NA   NA   NA
222    1    2    3    4
333    1    2    NA   NA
444    1    NA   NA   NA
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
id     manuf_1    manuf_2    manuf_3    manuf_4
111    AAA                                
222    AAA        BBB        CCC        DDD
333    CCC        DDD        
444    EEE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `value.var`, and mutate `rank` to your desired format before `dcast`

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(rank = paste0('manuf_', rank)) %>% 
  reshape2::dcast(id ~ rank, value.var = 'manufacturer')
#    id manuf_1 manuf_2 manuf_3 manuf_4
# 1 111     AAA    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 2 222     AAA     BBB     CCC     DDD
# 3 333     CCC     DDD    <NA>    <NA>
# 4 444     EEE    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

data used

```
df <- data.table::fread('
id      manufacturer    rank
111     AAA             1
222     AAA             1
222     BBB             2
222     CCC             3
222     DDD             4
333     CCC             1
333     DDD             2
444     EEE             1
')
```